# Java String match using the regex for optional String

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java String which I need to compare with the regex but these string can consist of the optional values which may be present or not present I need to perform different things based on their availability:

String 1: With serial

```
uri =  https://myid.com/123/1234567890128/456/1111
```

String 2: Without Serial

```
uri = https://myid.com/123/1234567890128
```

As we can see the incoming string can have the `/456/1111` or it may not have. How can I write a single regex function which checks whether it is present or not? I have written a regex but it would work only if the `/456/1111` is present:

```
uri.matches("(http|https)://.*/123/[0-9]{13}.*)")
```

I tried adding the optional values after looking at some of the answers here something like this:

```
uri.matches("(http|https)://.*/123/[0-9]{13}+([/456/[0-9]{1,20}]?)")
```

But for some reason, it does not work. Can someone please help me how can I verify whether there are any strings present in uri `/456/1111` or not. I feel like I am missing some small thing.

Comment: Like this? `https?://[^/]*/123/\d{1,13}(?:/456/\d{1,20})?` or `https?://.*/123/\d{1,13}(?:/456/\d{1,20})?$` https://regex101.com/r/gcniDs/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
^https?:\/\/.*\/123\/[0-9]{1,13}(?:/456/[0-9]{1,20})?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/wAjUbU/1).

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123                      '123'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{1,13}              any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                           and 13 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /456/                    '/456/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{1,20}              any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                             and 20 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. This explains a lot of things that I wasn't aware of :)

Answer (score 1):

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is your friend in this regard.

When looking at your [regex on that site](https://regex101.com/r/OLRoEv/1), you can see some errors like:

- you have a lone `]` at the end which seems off
- and at last your `?` at the end targets the wrong group, move it out of the parenthesis.

Something like [`https?://[^/]+/123/\d{13}(?:/456/\d{1,20})?`](https://regex101.com/r/LBuuMc/1)  should work for you.

The good thing about regex101 is that on the right side you see a detailed explanation about your regex, and it highlights exactly which character does what.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the pattern that you tried does not work, is because in the last part of your pattern you have `([/456/[0-9]{1,20}]?)` which means:

- `(` Capture group

  - `[/456/[0-9]{1,20}` Match 1-20 repetitions of either `/` or a digit 0-9 (as 0-9 also matches 456)
  - `]?` Match optional `]`
- `)` Close group

---

What you could do instead, is making the last group as a whole optional without a character class use `https?` making the s optional.

```
^https?://.*/123/[0-9]{13}(?:/456/[0-9]{1,20})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MfPgCT/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tCn77R)

As you use `matches()` it should match the whole string and you can omit the anchors `^` and `$`

```
String uri1 =  "https://myid.com/123/1234567890128/456/1111";
String uri2 = "https://myid.com/123/1234567890128";
String uri3 = "https://myid.com/123/1234567890128/456/111122222222222222222";
String pattern = "https?://.*/123/[0-9]{13}(?:/456/[0-9]{1,20})?";

System.out.println(uri1.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(uri2.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(uri3.matches(pattern));
```

Output

```
true
true
false
```